# Generate Number of Column and Number of Rows on user input

Tags: javascript, html

How can I generate a table with number of columns and rows from user input?

I want to offer two input fields to the user for row and column numbers to create the table on a button click.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: actually i am a beginner and i have been given task of creating table from user input using javascript. i would really appreciate any help to complete this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using a for loop for example

```
function createTable(r, c) {

  var tb = document.createElement('table');

  for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = 0; j < c; j++) {
      var column = document.createElement('td');
      column.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" row:"+i + " column:"+j));
      row.appendChild(column);
    }
    tb.appendChild(row);
  }

  return tb;
}
```

here's a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c6k9foeb/

[EDIT] fiddle with inputs https://jsfiddle.net/c6k9foeb/1/

[EDIT2] fiddle with text inputs on cells https://jsfiddle.net/c6k9foeb/2/

Comment: how i can do it using two input fields for column and row ?

Comment: thanks one last thing i want to add input text field in these rows and column can you help me do it.

Comment: thanks i just wondering to assign field name or id to every input field. i tried but its not showing on generated fields.

Comment: just put "input.name = x", you should use google, it's not that hard to search for it, for example check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_text.asp

Comment: i tried input.name = 'field'+i; but it creates field0 on first row and field1 on second and respectively. can you do make it seperate on every field.

Comment: what do you mean by separate?

Comment: i mean unique name for every field not repeating itself on either row or column

Comment: use input.name = 'field'+i+j for example

Comment: co-incidence just tried it before reading your comment, it works thanks man for the help.

Comment: i really appreciate it :)

Comment: i accepted it i need more help about it i also need to remove rows and columns as needed can you help me @arop